# Given everything is Dhamma , isn't it true that he who sees me sees Dhamma?

Tags: dhammas

Most people interpret almost everything as Dhamma. And it is said that Sabbe Dhamma Anatta.

Given everything is Dhamma , isn't it true that he who sees me sees Dhamma?

Answer (score 3):

If the seer lives,

> *Yathā-bhūta-ñāna-dassana*: 'the knowledge and vision according to
>   reality'

then yes, she can see Dhamma seeing you.

Comment: In other words, most people, particularly those who "interpret", are not "seeing" the Dhamma. They are merely thinking about it, intellectually or philosophically.

Answer (score 1):

The term "dhamma" has different meanings in Buddhism depending on context. You can find this on the [wisdomlib page on dhamma](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/dhamma#pali).

In "sabbe dhamma anatta", the term "dhamma" means phenomena. So, yes. When one looks at you, one looks at a phenomena.

But when the Buddha said "Truly seeing me, one sees the Dhamma; truly seeing the Dhamma, one sees me" in Vakkali Sutta, he specifically meant Dhamma the teachings.

It's a figure of speech meaning that to understand what the Buddha is all about and to understand what is important and special about the Buddha,  you have to understand his teachings.

Although Dhamma the teachings is also a phenomena which is not self.

Comment: How are you sure that seeing Buddha one sees that Dhamma which means his teachings where as seeing me one doesn't see Buddha's teachings ?

Comment: It's a figure of speech meaning that to understand what the Buddha is all about and to understand what is important and special about the Buddha,  you have to understand his teachings.

Answer (score 1):

I understood it as meaning that the Buddha lives in accordance with the Dhamma -- that he practices what he preaches -- so if you see the Buddha then you see the Dhamma enacted or embodied; but, also, that there's no benefit to you (or to [the Ven. Vakkali](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.087x.wlsh.html)) in seeing the Buddha in person, no benefit that you wouldn't get equally or more so from seeing the Dhamma yourself.

Comment: I couldnt get the answer about me as Dhamma.Currently as I am living with all the wrong views and right views , is it ok to say that one who sees me sees the Dhamma ?

Comment: I don't know what it would mean, to say that. "Dhamma" is a word with a broad meaning or many meanings -- [definitions here](https://suttacentral.net/define/dhamma). In some contexts (the Vakkali Sutta) it's interpreted to mean "*the* Dhamma" sometimes also called "the teaching" or "the Buddha-Dharma". I don't understand what "Most people interpret almost everything as Dhamma" might mean.

Comment: I am using the same context as Buddha used for himself when he said one who sees me sees the Dhamma and one who sees the Dhamma sees me.  When I said most people interpret almost everything as Dhamma I meant that all conditioned and unconditioned are considered as Dhamma, that includes all.